# Rebuild Expression

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda, expression

I have an expression like: `Expression<Func<TheObject, int, bool>> myExpression = (myObj, theType) => { myObj.Prop > theType };`

I need to dynamically rebuild myExpression to a new expression of type `Expression<Func<TheObject, bool>>` and replace “theType” parameter from the first expression with a concrete value 123 like:

```
Expression<Func<TheObject, bool>> myNewExpression = myObj => { myObj.Prop > 123 };
```

How can I do that?
Br
Philip

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? In the runtime?

Comment: You don't have `Expression`s there... Remove the `{` and the `}`, **then** you'll have `Expression`s (see http://goo.gl/Sl86ie)

Comment: I have a method that takes the first expression as a parameter and the integer value as a delegate this should return the new expression like: `Expression<Func<TheObject, bool>> RebuildExpression(Expression<Func<TheObject, int, bool>> myExpression, Func<int> theInt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple expression replacer it is quite easy:

This is the one I've written for myself... supports simple replaces and multiple replaces.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

// A simple expression visitor to replace some nodes of an expression 
// with some other nodes. Can be used with anything, not only with
// ParameterExpression
public class SimpleExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public readonly Dictionary<Expression, Expression> Replaces;

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        Replaces = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { from, to } };
    }

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(Dictionary<Expression, Expression> replaces)
    {
        // Note that we should really clone from and to... But we will
        // ignore this!
        Replaces = replaces;
    }

    public SimpleExpressionReplacer(IEnumerable<Expression> from, IEnumerable<Expression> to)
    {
        Replaces = new Dictionary<Expression, Expression>();

        using (var enu1 = from.GetEnumerator())
        using (var enu2 = to.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                bool res1 = enu1.MoveNext();
                bool res2 = enu2.MoveNext();

                if (!res1 || !res2)
                {
                    if (!res1 && !res2)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (!res1)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("from shorter");
                    }

                    throw new ArgumentException("to shorter");
                }

                Replaces.Add(enu1.Current, enu2.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        Expression to;

        if (node != null && Replaces.TryGetValue(node, out to))
        {
            return base.Visit(to);
        }

        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Your TheObject

```
public class TheObject
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Then you only need to replace the 2nd parameter in the body of the expression and rebuild the `Expression<>`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Func<TheObject, int, bool>> myExpression = (myObj, theType) => myObj.Prop > theType;

        int value = 123;

        var body = myExpression.Body;

        var body2 = new SimpleExpressionReplacer(myExpression.Parameters[1], Expression.Constant(value)).Visit(body);

        Expression<Func<TheObject, bool>> myExpression2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<TheObject, bool>>(body2, myExpression.Parameters[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, Thank you! Works perfect!

Comment: `SimpleExpressionReplacer ` is a well written class!